# How can i convert 1415071800000 to utc time in jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, datetime, utc

I am working with full calendar and giving JSON data to calendar. It displays right time on my local system but when I see it online it shows me wrong time. I want to add events by converting the time into UTC time but by using following code I get the `UtCTime = NaN`. Can anyone please explain how can I convert it.

```
v.appoint_starttime.match=/Date(1415071800000)/ ;
var newLocalStartDate = new Date(v.appoint_starttime.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1); 
var UtCTime = Date.UTC(newLocalStartDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

You should have variable `v` defined already, then remove `.match` from `v.appoint_starttime.match` and put double quotes around date value.

```
v.appoint_starttime="/Date(1415071800000)/" ;
var newLocalStartDate = new Date(v.appoint_starttime.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1); 
var UtCTime = Date.UTC(newLocalStartDate);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p74a03an/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your date.

```
var newLocalStartDate = new Date(parseInt(v.appoint_starttime.substr(6)));
```

substr function takes the length as 6 ie it ignores the initial 6 characters which include /Date(

The parseInt () function will parse the date string -> v.appoint_starttime.

Comment: Try to add a little detail about what you have posted.